Ansible dynamic inventory with terraform
I have an EC2 instance with Jenkins, Ansible and Terraform installed.What i want to do is to create a Jenkins job which runs a Terraform script for creating a new EC2 instance and Ansible playbook for installing Tomcat in the new one. My problem is that when i run terraform apply i want to have in inventory file the new ip of the instance. How can i change that ip everytime i create a new instance?
Here it is a part of main.tf file:
resource "aws_instance" "my_vm" {
  ami           = var.ami //Linux AMI
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = "DevOpsKey_Licenta"

  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.terra_tomcat_sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  tags = {
    Name = var.name_tag
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip} >> /opt/infrastructure-pipeline/inventory"
  } 
}

I tried to add every time the new IP with that command but also i have the last one.
Here is inventory file:
[tomcat]
32.153.123.41
12.100.99.3


You want to override the old instance IP?

yes, i want to override the old ip

You can use > instead of >> with the echo command.

Thanks! I got another problem now, when i run it as a jenkins job i get permission denied because jenkins runs the server as ec2-user and can’t modify the inventory file. How can i solve?

Not sure I follow. How is Jenkins running the server? Which server is it running?

Jenkins runs on first server created with Terraform. Now from this EC2 instance named JenkinsInstance i want to create a job which creates another Instance using Terraform. The new instance is named TomcatInstance. The problem is that when Jenkins job runs main.tf it creates the instance but when it must run provisioning local-exec i get permission denied. It can not change the inventory file content because jenkins is not running as root

Have you tried running it with sudo?

How? Something like that ?provisioner "local-exec" {
command = "sudo echo ${aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip} >> /opt/infrastructure-pipeline/inventory"
}

Well, if that's the command that's not working, yes. Otherwise, that's a completely different question compared to the original one.

@CapMarian See my comment in your followup question, but the root cause here is split between your Pipeline code and your Terraform config, and so you would probably need some sort of combined question that displays both. The root cause is currently unrelated to Ansible.

Instead of using a provisioner for this, I'd suggest to use the local_file resource type provided by the hashicorp/local provider. This will cause Terraform to "manage" the output file in a similar sense as how it would manage your EC2 instance, updating it as necessary if the configured content changes on a future run.
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
    local = {
      source = "hashicorp/local"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "my_vm" {
  ami           = var.ami //Linux AMI
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = "DevOpsKey_Licenta"

  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.terra_tomcat_sg.id]
  associate_public_ip_address = true

  tags = {
    Name = var.name_tag
  }
}

resource "local_file" "ansible" {
  filename = "/opt/infrastructure-pipeline/inventory"
  content = <<-EOT
    [tomcat]
    ${aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip}
  EOT
}

This declarative approach directly solves the problem described in the question, of replacing the old IP address with new each time the IP address changes rather than only appending. The configuration above makes Terraform responsible for the entirety of the file, and so whenever aws_instance.my_vm.public_ip changes the hashicorp/local provider will propose to rewrite the file to include only the new value.
An important caveat of using Terraform to manage local files is that you will need to always run Terraform on the specific computer where that file is located. Terraform is normally used to manage objects accessible over the network rather than on local disk, but as long as you only plan and apply this Terraform configuration on the computer where /opt/infrastructure-pipeline/inventory lives, and make sure it gets preserved between Terraform runs, Terraform will treat it just like any other managed object.

I tried, it modify but if i run it from a jenkins job i get permission denied to modify inventory file cuz it runs as jenkins user, not as root. Any ideeas?

You will need to somehow arrange for the Terraform process to have access to write that file. That isn't really something you can solve with Terraform, because Terraform itself is the one that's constrained by the permissions. Perhaps you could add a new user account to your system and configure sudo to allow the Jenkins user to run Terraform as that user, or use a separate Jenkins agent that runs as a user that can write to that file.

I'm not a Jenkins expert so I can't really suggest anything specific. If your main remaining problem is how to grant a process running in a Jenkins job access to modify a file outside the context of the job's working directory then you might get a better answer by asking a new question that's tagged as being a Jenkins question, so that Jenkins experts are more likely to find it.

It's probably also worth thinking about why the local-exec command was apparently able to write to that file but the local_file resource type cannot. They should both be running as the same system user and so should have equivalent permissions, but apparently that's not true. Maybe the explanation for why that isn't true will give a further idea for how to make this work. Perhaps the Jenkins user has access to write to the file but not to the directory containing the file, and so it isn't possible for Terraform to replace the existing file; you could change the directory permissions if so.
